# Can't run PhantomJS with mocha on node js

Tags: node.js, testing, error-handling, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to run phantomjs with these params:

```
mocha-phantomjs -s disk-cache=no --ignore-leaks -R xunit tests/index.html
```

but allways got this respond:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

I use ubuntu 13, mocha-phantomjs 3.1.0 and node v0.10.15.

Any googling doesn't helps and I just can't figure out what to do.
All what i did before, is just install node and mocha-phantomjs

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This can happen on Windows as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this error on a windows machine, and solved it by copying phantomjs executable to the node.js folder.

Make sure that either 
phantomjs executable is in PATH
or
phantomjs executable is in node.js folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another option on Windows, that's slightly cleaner:

[Download Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/download.html). Decompress the zip someplace (`c:\dev\phantom` or whatever) and add it to your path.

Install mocha-phantomjs globally using npm:

```
npm install -g mocha-phantomjs
```

And you should be all set.